# Python to CSV is splitting string into two columns when I want one

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page with BeautifulSoup, and part of the logic is that sometimes part of the contents of a `<td>` tag can have a `<br>` in it.

So sometimes it looks like this:

```html
<td class="xyz">
    text 1
    <br>
    text 2
</td>
```

and sometimes it looks like this:

```html
<td class="xyz">
    text 1
</td>
```

I am looping through this and adding to an output_row list that I eventually add to a list of lists.  Whether I see the former format or the latter, I want the text to be in one cell.

I've found a way to determine if I am seeing the `<br>` tag because the td.string shows up as none and I also know that text 2 always has 'ABC' in it.  So:

```python
    elif td.string == None:
        if 'ABC' in td.contents[2]:
            new_string = td.contents[0] + ' ' + td.contents[2]
            output_row.append(new_string)
            print(new_string)
        else:    
            #this is for another situation and it works fine
```

As I print this in a Jupyter Notebook, it shows up as "text 1 text 2" as one line.  But when I open up my CSV, it is in two different columns.  So when td.string has contents (meaning no `<br>` tag), text 1 shows up in one column, but when I get to the pieces that have a `<br>` tag, all my data gets shifted.

I'm not sure why it shows up as two different strings (two columns) when I concatenate them before appending them to the list.

I'm writing to file like this:

```python
with open('C:/location/file.csv', 'w',newline='') as csv_file:
    writer=csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    #writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in output_rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

csv_file.close
```

Comment: How are you writing the file?

Comment: Added in an edit to the OP.

Comment: sorry if I'm missing something, but couldn't you just call `''.join(td.text.split())` to remove any `<br>`s and fix it that way?

Comment: Everything looks OK with the sample input. Does the resulting string of `td.contents[0] + ' ' + td.contents[2]` contain a comma? If so, it will cause what you're experiencing. Also, your `csv_file.close` isn't actually closing the file as you're not actually calling it. Also, if you _were_ to call it, it would raise an exception - `with` implicitly closes open files. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks to all.  The split, and the get_text() function both worked.  I realize my (stupid) error in Jupyter was that I wasn't running a cell above it to reset my output_rows and I just kept getting the same thing. Thanks for the get_text() function though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle both cases using [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) with "strip" and "separator":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dat="""
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="xyz">
            text 1
            <br>
            text 2
        </td>

        <td class="xyz">
            text 1
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(dat, 'html.parser')
for td in soup.select("table > tr > td.xyz"):
    print(td.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
text 1 text 2
text 1
```

Comment: I agree this is a better method of _getting the data_, but if I understand the question properly, the issue is that the string is split into two columns when writing to csv. I suspect there is a `,` in the actual data OP is writing to file.

Comment: @That1Guy good point, it might not be the direct answer to the question after all. I suspect your "data contains comma" theory is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @That1Guy Thanks!  Weirdly, there were commas in the string, but they weren't getting separated out.  The reason I was getting 2 columns was because I wasn't resetting my list and I kept making changes and the print out would change, but now the export to csv.